# Changing The Value Stored In A Particular Address in C++

Tags: c++

I have recently started object-oriented software development in C++ and I am having a few issues trying to understand pointers. I am using Qt Creator 3.3.0.

**1. Using (*type) To Store A New Address In The Variable**

why I am always required to do:

```
 int* y = ( int*) 0x61fe9c;
```

To store and address rather than:

```
 int* y = 0x61fe9c;
```

Shouldn't the pointer understand that I am storing a hexadecimal address of a memory location ?

**2. Storing A New Particular Address In A Pointer**

I am trying to understand why once you store a particular address in a pointer you have to do it in a different way to store a new address:

```
int* y = ( int*) 0x61fe9c;
*y = 0x61fe9d;
```

If I do this the the address is stored without any problems but if I want to store it in this other way:

```
*y = (int*) 0x61fe9d;
```

The compiler gives me the error of `invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'`.

Why can I not change the value of the address stored as shown above ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with object-oriented anything. Why do you think you need something like `int* y = ( int*) 0x61fe9c;`? Where did you learn about this particular address? How do you know you won't break the world by touching it?

Comment: "I am using Qt Creator 3.3.0" - Wow, that's *old*.

Comment: There is almost no case where it is the right thing to do to assign a literal constant address to a pointer. *IF* you were doing some kind of embedded programming you'd probably use a linker script instead and define addresses there. *OR* you'd use something like the Linux device tree which is a data structure describing the system and its devices. *OR* you'd implement a bus protocol like PCI or USB which has data structures describing where to find the device addresses. And you'd *probably* use ACPI to find the PCI bus addresses.

Answer (score 2):

> why I am always required to do:
>
> ```
> int* y = ( int*) 0x61fe9c;
> ```
>
> To store and address rather than:
>
> ```
> int* y = 0x61fe9c;
> ```

Because C++ has a strong type system.

The type system has been designed to prevent programmers from making mistakes, by unintentionally assigning a value of one type into an object of another type. Instead of allowing arbitrary things to happen at run-time, such programs are ill-formed (except for example when one type is implicitly convertible to the other type; this is not such case).

In this case, you're attempting to assign an integer to a pointer. Such operation is quite unusual, and you must explicitly convert the value of integer type into a pointer pointer type.

> I am trying to understand why once you store a particular address in a pointer you have to do it in a different way to store a new address:
>
> ```
> *y = 0x61fe9d;
> ```

This doesn't store an address in the pointer i.e. this doesn't make the pointer point to another memory location. You indirect through the pointer using the indirection operator (the unary `*`), so the value of the expression is the pointed object, not the pointer itself.

To change the value of the pointer, don't indirect through it:

```
y = address_of_another_object;
```

> ```
> *y = (int*) 0x61fe9d;
> ```
>
> The compiler gives me the error of `invalid conversion from 'int*' to`
> 'int'.

Just like above the type system prevents you from assigning value of one type into an object of another type, except in the other direction. In this case you attempt to assign a pointer value into an integer object.

Since your intention appears to not have been to modify the pointed object, it appears that the type system saved you from your mistake.

---

P.S. The behaviour of accessing the memory by indirecting through the pointer is undefined, unless you've created an object there. And you cannot create an object in arbitrary memory location unless you've allocated the memory. And there is no standard way of allocating memory at an arbitrary location.

The only situation where indirecting through an integer literal converted to a pointer makes sense that I know of is some embedded systems where documented addresses communicate with the hardware. In such case, you should probably need to qualify the pointed type as `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

> If I do this the the address is stored without any problems

`*y = 0x61fe9d;` just stores the value `6422173` (decimal representation of 0x61fe9d) in an address pointed to by y.

> The compiler gives me the error of invalid conversion from 'int*' to
>   'int'.

`*y = (int*) 0x61fe9d;` gives an error because you are trying to store a pointer variable to an int type.

> Why can I not change the value of the address stored as shown above ?

Just do `y = (int*) 0x61fe9d;`

Or per @user463035818 and @Quentin's comment, as a better practice, use `reinterpret_cast` to get compile time safety.

`y = reinterpret_cast<int*>(0x61fe9d);`

Comment: better use `static_cast<int*>`

Comment: You're looking for `reinterpret_cast`, `static_cast` does not do pointer/integral conversions.

Comment: ups sorry for the misinformation ;) I always try `static_cast` first and if does not work I think twice if I am really doing the right thing

Comment: Anything requiring `reinterpret_cast` is a *huge* red flag saying "you are probably doing it wrong"..